# Mass file generation with razor

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, service, report

I have to produce many text files on some event, for example, on end of a business day. These files contain data entries and will be consumed by several enterprise systems. To solve this task (I work with Microsoft technologies) I can use Biztalk, XSLT or some template engines. Not all template engines are suitable for me. So, whereas I can apply NVelocity (open-source, but robust and reliable) I cannot use T4, since T4 is NOT aimed for massive file generations and has multi-threading limitations.

**Question:** What prevents me from using Razor engine and creating some Windows-service, which creates these files? Are there any limitations for using Razor for massive file generation (for example, multi-threading support or something else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had really good expierience with Razor hosted outside ASP envirnoment, for rendering emails for example. I used [Razo Engine](https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/) (v2)  and do not have any problems with multithreading and memeory leaks. Highly recommended it. Moreover in v3 they natively support parallel template rendering [An early look at RazorEngine v3](http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=473)

Comment: Thank you, most helpful.